# Angular Private Inner Interface (aka Typescript Nested Class)

Tags: angular, typescript

### How can I use a nested interface in an Angular directive?

In Java, I find static nested classes a great way to organize code. I'd like to do the same in Typescript/Angular but am having trouble getting it all setup.

The code below comes close to working. But I'm having trouble with whether I export the namespace or not

If I do, then I can't declare the directive in the module that holds it. I get the following warning:

> MyDirective is not declared in any Angular module.

If I do not, then I have trouble typing objects as `MyDirective.DirectiveOptions` because of the following error:

> TS2702: 'MyDirective' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

My directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appMyDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    defaultDirectiveOptions: MyDirective.DirectiveOptions = {
        callback: () => {console.log('default callback called')}
    };

    @Input('appMyDirective')
    directiveOptions: MyDirective.DirectiveOptions = {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.directiveOptions = {...this.defaultDirectiveOptions, ...this.directiveOptions};
    }
}

// Seems like a dumb way to nest an interface, but whatever.
export namespace MyDirective {
    export interface DirectiveOptions {
        callback?: () => void;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in a `foo.component.ts` file:

```
options: MyDirective.DirectiveOptions = {
    callback: ()=>{
        console.log('Overridden callback called');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-options 

Oddly enough this seems to work as is (if the namespace is exported) in stack-blitz. Perhaps the problem is just intellij adding a needless warning.

Comment: I'm curious What does nesting the interface gives you? It looks like you could just declare the DirectiveOptions interface without nesting it in a namespace. When you import it into foo.component.ts you can then give it a nice name, eg import * as MyDirective from 'MyDirectiveFile'.

Comment: @matthelliwell It gives me nothing but the name-spacing. It's an encapsulation mechanism. Not at all necessary but this type of ordering of the world is satisfying to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the original code in the question works as good as anything I can find. If you have a better solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring an interface consisting a property of another interface like this one?

```
export interface MyDirective {
    directiveOptions: DirectiveOptions
}

export interface DirectiveOptions {
    callback?: () => void;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is what I would normally do, but if I have several different directives, I like the naming convention of not needing to give unique names to each options object for each directive.

Answer (score 0):

So, you create namespace and class with one name. Please take into consideration, that Angular compiles to JavaScript. And JS did not has Classes and namespaces. All things will compile to functions. Thats why you get such message.